# pandas export a vector and change its shape to 1d array

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have a pd.dataframe

```
df = {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]}
```

I can create an ndarray of the col2 by doing this:

```
col2 = np.array(df['col2'].values)
```

I want to add a number as the first element of this vector, I tried this:

```
col2=np.array([0])
col2=col2.append( np.array(df['col2'].values))
```

but it gives error.

I have also tried concatenate and (df['col2'].values).tolist()
but I am not able to solve the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`np.append` is inefficient for concatenation tasks. You can use `np.hstack` or `np.concatenate` instead. Also note [`pd.Series.values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.values.html) returns a NumPy array, so there's no need to cast explicitly via `np.array`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]})

col2 = np.array([0])
col2 = np.hstack((col2, df['col2'].values))

# array([0, 3, 4], dtype=int64)
```

As @user3483203 comments, NumPy arrays aren't a necessity, although you'll see a marginal speed improvement. You can use `list` and `pd.Series` objects with `np.hstack`:

```
col2 = np.hstack(([0], df['col2']))
```

Comment: You don't even need to call `values`: `np.hstack(([0], df.col2))`.  `hstack` can work with Series just fine.  You'll get a *very* minor speed boost from operating on the array, but the difference won't increase at large sizes